# Do you say 'white blackboard'?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

English is not my first language, so I'm not sure what you commonly call one of these:

[image: Whiteboard]

I'm trying to choose between blackboard, white blackboard, or maybe just 'slate'.

Comment: That's a terrible sin(x)!

Comment: The cuerpo is even worse.

Comment: What's wrong with whiteboard?

Comment: I just ignored the existance of that word since I'm no English speaker.

Comment: @vemv: I am guessing that you speak a language such as French where "ignore" or its cognate means "not know". It has a different meaning in English: it means "intentionally avoid acknowledging". So "I ignored the existence of that word" to an English speaker means "I pretended that word didn't exist (but I knew it did really)" [Just telling you this to be helpful, not meaning to belittle you.]

Comment: Much appreciated! In fact I was doubting whether the English version of 'ignore' had this double meaning or not. My bad for not checking it.

Comment: came here to comment about whiteboard and notice that I ignore -sorry, I didn't know- the meaning of ignore

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That is quite simply a whiteboard.

[Blackboard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blackboard) can be defined as:

> A smooth, hard, dark-colored panel for writing on with chalk.

[Whiteboard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whiteboard) can be defined as:

> A panel covered with white, glossy plastic for writing on with erasable markers.

Comment: There has also been a trend in recent decades to replace "blackboard" by "chalkboard". This does not affect whiteboards, however.

Comment: @Jasper: Same here, hence "chalkboard".

Comment: There are however *black* whiteboards for writing with neon-bright erasable markers.

Comment: oh, green boards. I thought it was because of political correctness brought to an extreme.

Comment: When whiteboards began to replace blackboards, I was still in school. The rumour was that they called it so because it was racist to have blackboards, but not whiteboards!! LOL

Comment: The whole "chalkboard" thing is largely mythic.

Answer (score 30):

I most often hear these referred to as [dry erase boards](http://images.google.com/images?q=dry%20erase%20board&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&biw=1280&bih=705).

[image]

Comment: This was the original term, so +1. "Whiteboard" has since become the shorthand, since dry erase markers aren't the only things that work on them, and some things actually work better for certain situations (for instance, Vis-a-Vis wet-erase markers don't rub off when someone brushes past the board)

Comment: Interestingly, [Staples Online refers to the category](http://www.staples.com/Boards-Easels/cat_CG101?searchkey=whiteboards&storeId=10001&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&fromUrl=home) as "whiteboards" but all the individual products are sold as "dry-erase boards".  And the markers are only sold as "dry-erase markers".

Comment: The markers are "dry-erase" to differentiate them from "wet-erase" markers, which are used on overhead transparencies and required a wet rag to erase.  Wet-erase markers are also useful on dry-erase boards, for markings that you don't want to erase with the dry-erase parts. For example, for a status list, you could write the team members' names in wet erase and the status in dry erase. This makes it hard to erase the name when erasing the status.

Comment: Tangential trick I learned in the army(!): you can draw on top of wet-erase lines with dry-erase markers and they will then dry-erase away.

Comment: @Henrik N: I learned that at middle school, and again in high school, and again in university. My elementary uses chalkboard.

Comment: I differentiate between whiteboards and dry-erase boards: the larger ones (such as you might find in a classroom) are usually "whiteboards" (though "dry-erase boards" also works), but smaller ones (like in the picture in this answer) are *always* "dry-erase boards" (calling it a "whiteboard" seems a bit funny to me). Does anyone else do this?

Answer (score 10):

That is, quite naturally, called [whiteboard](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/whiteboard#whiteboard_5), [Bierce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil%27s_Dictionary) does not have an entry for the word but it would probably be:

- the writing board that always get written on with permanent marker

Comment: Indelible ink on a whiteboard? Now, that's unreasonable. If it _always_ gets written on with such, it will soon cease to be white; and space in which to write will likewise become scarce indeed.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, see details on Bierce's dictionary - http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict3&Database=devils

Comment: Hahaha. Cheers for the answers.

Comment: @Unreason: That link gives me no immediate explanation - am I to read the entire thing?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: (at the risk of spoiling a joke by explaining it) that site is full of cynical or ironic pseudo-definitions.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - Ambrose Bierce's *Devil's Dictionary* is worth reading under any circumstances, but @Unreason is simply referring to the way he defined things in terms of their unintended consequences, or in terms of the (wrong) ways they inevitably get used.  Imagine Murphy's Law crossed with the OED, and you get the *Devil's Dictionary*.  So Bierce probably would have defined "whiteboard" just as @Unreason did.

Comment: Years ago I worked in a corporate MIS department; we got the news that we had a new CIO, a purported business genius with a shiny new MBA.  He came in to describe his vision for our exciting future; of course, he ignored the erasable markers attached to the whiteboard, and instead wrote with Magic Markers he'd picked up in the office next door.  His "vision" for our "future" was laughable; the company was failing and our division was closed a year later... but right up until the end we had to write *around* his bullet points. I lost a lot of respect for the significance of an MBA that day.

Comment: @MT_Head. Acetone is wonderful stuff. It'll dissolve anything.

Comment: "If it _always_ gets written on with such..." - I would argue that 'always' could mean 'it'll invariably happen at least once to any given whiteboard'. (Also, since it's a glossy surface, it _is_ possible to remove the ink - I've done so without chemical assistance - it's just rather difficult)

Comment: @Colin Fine: After reading the first few lines I had began to think as much. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TRiG - You're telling me this about twenty years too late... my first couple of attempts at cleaning the board were far too harsh, and the corner where I'd been scrubbing was no longer erasable (but his blather was still visible!)  So we decided to leave well enough alone and not experiment anymore on the rest of the board.  I will keep acetone in mind, in case I ever again have to deal with an MBA armed with a Magic Marker.

Comment: @MT_Head: Writing over permanent marker (ie. Sharpie) with dry-erase markers will usually allow erasure of the permanent marker as well. I have a whiteboard that's been gridded with Sharpie, and it needs to be touched up every so often because the erased dry-erase marker leaves gaps in the grid.

Comment: @chaosys - I've hardly ever used a whiteboard since I left that company, but I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol, a component in most whiteboard cleaning sprays, will erase Sharpie, Magic Marker, and other "permanent" markers from whiteboards. This is because these markers are alcohol-based. (In my line of work, electronics, we can't use Sharpies to mark circuit boards because we clean them with alcohol, which quickly removes the ink. We must use paint markers or label printers instead.)

Comment: @chaosys, Yes, the whiteboard markers are, I think, basically permanent marker plus solvent, so when you write over permanent marker, the permanent marker is dissolved. But a whiteboard cleaner such as 2-propanol (isopropyl alcohol), acetone (nail-polish remover) or any other organic solvent should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I refer to it as simply a whiteboard.

Answer (score 4):

Also in common use is the generic term "the board", since most rooms only have a single whiteboard or chalkboard so there is no need to disambiguate between them.

For instance: "Student, please go write the answer on the board."

Answer (score 2):

"Blackboard," has a nice archaic ring to it.  I started in elementary school with blackboards, then they turned green, and we still called them blackboards.  Now they're white, but to me it will stay a blackboard no matter what color it is.

"White blackboard," I've never heard used, except by sarcastic teens mocking my age.

"Slate," would confuse Americans, and, I belive, is not techincally correct since a "slate" is an individual item that one writes on, like a tablet, not something that is big enough to nail to the wall and show the room; that would be a big chunk of rock indeed.

So, if you want to be accurate, "dry erase board."  But accuracy is boring and ugly.

Comment: Nice contribution. And the humorous touches make it only better :)

Answer (score 2):

The dry-erase boards are called simply "whiteboards" or I've heard "[greaseboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteboard)."

Comment: Those were for actual grease.  Well, "grease pencils", which are actually wax pencils, which are what children call "crayons", but the people using grease pencils are engaged in important, grown-up work, too busy to use "crayons".