# Chalkboard and Blackboard Difference?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

Can "chalkboard" and "blackboard" be used interchangeably? If I have a green chalkboard, can I still call it a blackboard, or would that be incorrect?

Also, I have heard that "blackboard" is used more than "chalkboard" in certain areas, and am not sure about how true this is.

Comment: Technical terminology for frequently-used artifacts varies widely. In general, a green blackboard is called a blackboard. Either may be called a chalkboard. Consult local native speakers before using any other names.

Comment: Related: _[Do you say 'white blackboard'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31050/5822)_

Comment: In common use the two terms are interchangeable (though we used to say "greenboard" when I was in school, just to tweak the teachers).  The white magic-marker board is, however, a "whiteboard".

Comment: @John Lawler. I've always considered "chalkboard" to be American. I never heard it until long after I left school in 1961. They were always "blackboards". But when I returned to university in 2002, they were mostly white and called "whiteboards". Giles' (the cartoonist) had a schoolmaster character called "Chalkie".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *[blackboard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blackboard)* is:-

> a sheet of smooth, hard material, especially dark slate, used in
>   schools, lecture rooms, etc., for writing or drawing on with chalk.

whereas a *[chalkboard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chalkboard)* is:-

> A smooth hard panel, usually green or black, for writing on with
>   chalk; a blackboard.

A *[greenboard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/greenboard)* is:-

> a green chalkboard or blackboard.

Note that the second reference also defines *chalkboard* as:-

> (Social Science / Education) a US and Canadian word for blackboard

which leads us to the nub of the matter. I won't pussyfoot around the point here; *greenboard* and *chalkboard* were invented to avoid including the word *black*, which offends the political sensibilities of some people.

Comment: The cheeseboard is different altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this political correctness bit at the end. Most of the increase in frequency of *chalkboard* happened between 1945 and 1960, which I think was before most people were worrying about offending black people. [See Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chalkboard%2Cblackboard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: And in fact, it seems likely that the term "chalkboard" had nothing to do with the color of people's skin. From [this 1953 book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Rls_AAAAYAAJ&q=%22term+chalkboard+seems+more+appropriate%22&dq=%22term+chalkboard+seems+more+appropriate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o1EVUo7HHYPB4APR5IHgAw&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA): *If this information had been written several years ago, the title of this topic would have been "Illustrate on the Blackboard." Chalkboards now are made of several materials and come in various colors. Because of this the term chalkboard seems more appropriate.*

Comment: The chalkboards/blackboards in the parochial school which I attended as a kid were not exactly smooth in texture. They had fine and even rasp texture to enable them to hold onto the chalk drawn on them. A board is considered for replacement when its surface loses its rasp texture and becomes too smooth to retain chalk. Also, it is the raspness (i.e. non-smoothness) that allows the annoying chalk rasping sound we used to annoy each other when the teacher was not around. Incidentally, most of the blackboards were dark green, because of the same coating as on a table-tennis table.

Comment: When we used blackboards about 30 years ago in the school where I taught, most of them were black because we painted them with blackboard paint every year.

Comment: '[_G_] _reenboard_ and _chalkboard_ were invented to avoid including the word _black_, which offends the political sensibilities of some people.' Peter has given some fairly strong evidence to the contrary. Have you any supporting evidence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I was once rebuked for using the word _blackboard_ for exactly that reason; my interlocutor had similar objections to _black market_ and _blackmail_ (this was in the early nineties). But the dates given do, as you say, make it unlikely that this was the original reason. Perhaps it was a joke that has got out of control; that is certainly the case with the (originally) satirical _Baa Baa Green Sheep_.

Comment: I can understand the dislike of negative associations possibly brought to mind by 'black market' and 'blackmail' (and, by implication, 'play the white man'). But _blackboard_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, quite. I thought it was a joke, but the resulting huff tended to suggest otherwise. Or it was the finest piece of acting I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

When I was at school (in the 1960s, in the UK), our *blackboards* were neither black nor boards: they were green and were of a continuous sheet flexible material rotated on two rollers (top & bottom). But we still called them ***blackboards***!

**Addendum**
As far as I'm aware, the term *chalkboard* is not commonly used in the UK, but would, of course, be understood.

Comment: Nowadays they tend to be **white**. And don't get me started on *interactive (white) boards*, I don't find them at all **smart**!

Answer (score 4):

I would say the difference is more generational than anything else and the changeover from blackboard to chalkboard had nothing at all to do with racial sensibilities or political correctness. When I started school in 1955, they were all black and were called blackboards. In a new school I went to in 1957 the boards were green but since everyone was used to calling them blackboards, we kept the old name. (Just as we call the material in pencils "lead" even though it hasn't been lead but graphite for over a hundred years.)

I found that people who came along after the boards were different colors and no longer black tended to start calling them chalkboards. I'm not sure when this occurred, but probably sometime after 1960.

Comment: Some excellent points!